# Wordpress custom listing page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have WordPress site that has films and actor custom post types. Also I'm creating relationship with films and actors.

I have a page to list films that related to actor. On this page visitors can see in which films actor take role.

This pages URL is like this:

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/actors-films/?id=123456
```

`id` refers to the actor, with this `id` I'm doing a query and showing it on the page.
also this page supports pagination, this URL works too:

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/actors-films/page/2/?id=123456
```

`actors-film` page is a page that uses a custom template, this template determines the actor id and shows his films.

Every thing works fine, but I want to change the URL a little bit SEO friendly.

I have tried many URL formats

1. `http://www.mywebpage.com/actors-films/jim-carrey` 
   I don't know why but this URL redirects to actors page.

   ```
   http://www.mywebpage.com/actors/jim-carrey
   ```
2. `http://www.mywebpage.com/actors-films/123456-jim-carrey`
   I have tried to catch this kind of URL with `.htaccess` but no way to catch it, it always shows a 404 not found.

So, I need to do a rewrite with pagination support, can you please suggest me a way to do this?

edit : here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^actors-films/([0-9]*)\-([^/]*)$  ^actors-films/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit : I have realized that not rules works for me :
example :
http://www.mywebsite.com/tex shows a 404 with this rule : RewriteRule ^/tex /index.php [L]

Comment: show us your current `.htaccess` and change any sensitive information if any.

Comment: Try removing the `<IfModule>` tags around your rules. If you get an error then the rewrite module isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, create a page named

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'ap_register_query_vars');

function ap_url_redirect_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('actors-films/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=artist-film-list&actor_slug=$matches[1]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function ap_register_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[]='actor_slug';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Now we can call the url http://mywebsite.com/actors-films/john-doe